# How to have a configurable product with 2 or more of the same color on Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, configurable-product

I am currently running Magento 1.9.  and have a question about product configurable.

I am selling a product with multiple colors. For example, i have Light Pink, Rose Pink, and Hot Pink, they are all variations of Pink.

So can I have them all in the variation of Pink color?

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course your can :)

Assuming you have a simple for each colour variation, when you create your configurable with these simples, you will get a option dropdown showing each of the pinks.

As a side note, if you do not need to control the stock levels for each colour variation individually you would not need to create a configurable at all. You could have a simple product with a custom option of "Colour" with all your pink variations as the values.